# I'm trying to make a cigarette. I made the burn area and the ash, but I can't get them to combine. Can you guys help me?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Here are the nodes for the cigarette/ash parts. I don't know how to mix them. I tried mix shader, but my ash part overlays the paper texture.

The last picture is what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm waiting for your replies.

[image: Ash_part]

[image: Ash_nodes]

[image: Cigarette_burn]

[image: Cigarette_nodes]

[image: Mix]

[image: Reference_image]

Answer (score 1):

A mix shader should work just fine. Just make sure to use the same alpha factor that you used for the "burn mask".

[image: AshBurn]

Comment: I will try it when I get home tonight. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thank you Cristopher Bennett, that was really helpful, I forgot some mix nodes, this came out perfect. I really appreciate the time you took. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them with mix rgb node or a mix shader node, for this task I'll reccomend you to use mix shader node just plug both the colors/textures in a principal or shader you think is more preferable and combine them, now for the next part you can use a gradient texture with mapping node and object coordinates and plug it into the factor input( you may need to inverse it for that just invert the order of sockets you have plugged into mix shader, the lower one in upper and upper one in lower), now you can use a color ramp to tighten the gradient as per your liking and use mapping node to move or rotate it, you can even add a noise texture in middle of mapping node and object coordinate to make a random coming ash on paper.

Comment: I tried also mix rgb method, I tried mix shader also, the ash is overlaying my paper texture, I separated the burnt part with a math node set to absolute, I tried mixing my ash with my transparent part, but I can't get it to mix very well. Every time it shows up on my paper texture. What I want is ash on the right side of burn area and plain white paper texture on the left side from view. I tried even with a color ramp, I don't know exactly how to achieve the desired efect. I put a picture to see what I want to look like.

Comment: You just have to create a black and white texture, white for one and black for other and use it as your face, if it still doesn't help then you can send a link to your blend file that will help.